# How to pattern match a "string list * string list list" in Ocaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

a newbie in Ocaml here!

I have "string list * string list list" looking like this:

```
val employee : string list * string list list = 
(["Name"; "Salary"; "department"],
["James"; "52 000"; "A1"];
["Sarah"; "50 000"; "A1"];
["Peter"; "76 000"; "C3"];
["Jessica"; "93 000"; "D2"]])
```

I want to create a function that takes "employee", a list containing various combinations of `["Name"; "Salary"; "department"]` and returns a string with all the elements for that attribute. I.e. `#employeeInfo (["Name"], employee)` should return `["Name"; "James"; "Sarah"; "Peter"; "Jessica"]`. However, I am not sure how to pattern match a `string list * string list list` and I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: If you add the list of field descriptors to the front of the data list, then you just need to look up how to transpose a list of lists. Should be lots of previous questions on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps helpful to understand how a list in OCaml is built in order to understand how it's pattern-matched. So a quick and dirty list definition for demonstration purposes.

```
type 'a demo_list = Empty | List of 'a * 'a demo_list
```

A list is a recursive data type. It is either empty, or a value plus *some other* list which might either be empty or... well, the same. That can go on as long as we want it to.

What that means for pattern-matching a list is that you can match either an empty list, or the first element in a list and the rest.

```
match some_list with
| [] -> ...
| first::rest -> ...
```

Now, call `first` and `rest` whatever you want. `x` and `xs` are really common. There's nothing special about those names. They're just names.

When pattern-matching on a list, the `[]` pattern is a natural exit point for recursion. Typically with `first::rest` or `x::xs` we're doing something with that first value, and then recursively calling a function on `rest` or `xs`.

We can pattern match on more than the first and rest, but we can't pattern-match all elements in a list, because we can't know how long a list will be at compile-time as it can be of any length.

In your problem, that means pattern-matching on your employee tuples is going to be impossible, since we aren't interested in one at a time, but in parallel components of each.

But we can pattern match on the *headers* list.

I don't want to just give you code, but here's some ASCII diagrams. We'll start out with the type of table you've essentially described.

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| "A" | "B" | "C" |
+-----+-----+-----+
| "a" | "s" | "7" |
| "g" | "y" | "9" |
| "x" | "d" | "1" |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

If we consider the first row the headers, and it's a list. We run a `lookup` function that takes the header name we're looking for and the data table.

```
lookup "C" data
```

It matches on that first header list.

```
         +-----+          +-----+-----+
first -> | "A" |  rest -> | "B" | "C" |
         +-----+          +-----+-----+
```

But `first` does not equal `"C"` so we call the function recursively with `rest` and with mapping `List.tl` to the data.

```
         +-----+          +-----+
first -> | "B" |  rest -> | "C" |
         +-----+          +-----+

Data:

+-----+-----+
| "s" | "7" |
| "y" | "9" |
| "d" | "1" |
+-----+-----+
```

Still not what we're looking for because `"B"` is not equal to `"C"`. Let's try this again.

```
         +-----+          +-+
first -> | "C" |  rest -> | |
         +-----+          +-+

Data:

+-----+
| "7" |
| "9" |
| "1" |
+-----+
```

Now `"C"` *is* equal to `"C"` so we can return the result of mapping `List.hd` to the data and we'd get: `["7"; "9"; "1"]`.

Of course, if that last iteration hadn't worked, and we'd called `lookup` with an empty headers list, we'd know the field we're looking for isn't there, and a reasonable course of action would either be to raise an exception or refactor your function to use the `option` type and return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern in OCaml generally looks like the value it matches. A pattern that matches pairs `(x, y)` looks like `(p, q)`. So if you match your value `employee` against the pattern `(tags, values)`, `tags` will match `["Name"; "Salary"; "department"]` and `values` will match the list of lists.

You can combine patterns into larger ones. So the pattern `(tag :: tags, values)` matches a pair whose first element is a list. If you match this pattern against your value `employee`, `tag` will match "Name", `tags` will match `["Salary; "department"]` and `values` will match the list of lists.

You can continue in this way to build up whatever pattern you like. However, there's not going to be a single pattern match that calculates the function you want. It seems to me you will need some code that maps between the position of the tag and the pieces of the list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem

```
let rec position name = function
  | [] -> failwith "No column with that name"
  | hd::_ when hd = name -> 0
  | _::tail -> 1 + position name tail

let employee_info (headers, fields) attribute =
  let pos = position attribute headers in
  List.map (fun l -> List.nth l pos) fields
```

To be used like

```
utop # employee_info employees "Name"
- : string list = ["James"; "Sarah"; "Peter"; "Jessica"]
utop #
```

Comment: This can be done in a very straightforward way that doesn't involve calls to `List.nth` or finding the index of the header you're looking for. Iterate over the "headers". If you find the header you're looking for, map `List.hd` to the records and return that list. If not, call the function with the tail of the headers and map `List.tl` to the records. If you've run through the headers list and haven't found the one you're looking for, either raise an exception, or if you prefer to use the `option` type, return `None`.

Comment: @Chris Indeed, I agree your way of doing is better, among other reasons because it's easier to return `None` than to throw an exception, which seems better to me.